# How to serve static content with multiple websites/paths on Nginx?

Tags: nginx, iis, nginx-reverse-proxy, flutter-web, nginx-config

I've been following [this article](https://gist.github.com/soheilhy/8b94347ff8336d971ad0) trying to host multiple websites on the same machine using `IIS` and `Nginx`.

Based on the provided article I produced the following `nginx.conf`:

```
http {
    server {
        listen                 80;
        server_name            localhost;
        keepalive_timeout      1;
        gzip_types             text/css text/plain text/xml application/xml application/javascript application/x-javascript text/javascript application/json text/x-json;
        gzip_proxied           no-store no-cache private expired auth;
        gzip_disable           "MSIE [1-6]\.";

        # new website         
        location /bacon/ {
            proxy_pass          http://127.0.0.1:1500/;
            proxy_http_version  1.1;
            gzip_static         on;
        }

        # old website
        location / {
            proxy_pass          http://127.0.0.1:8881;
            proxy_http_version  1.1;
            gzip_static         on;
        }
    }
}
```

My `old website` is working just fine.

Yet when I try to access my `new website` I get the following errors:

[image]

Note that my `new website` works just fine if diretly requested trough `http://127.0.0.1:1500/`.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Hey @Rogerio Schmitt,


Your new "site" is actually just a path at localhost, not a separate "server name" e.g. <server_name>/bacon

Therefore, your requests should be to http://localhost/bacon
But looking at your console screenshot, it doesn't show the details the requests like Network tab would, which will be helpful for debugging...

Based upon the console error, i'm guessing that this is using express..

I would ask that you add the express file that is serving the routes, most likely you are only accounting for the index file, but not the static files, e.g. *.js

Comment: I would recommend adding the following to express to see if this solves the console error. `app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/'));`

Comment: @chrismillah Yes requests are being made to localhost/bacon. I'm not using `express`, as stated in my question `IIS` is being used.

Comment: okay -- what are you proxying to? is that IIS serving an application on that specific port :1500?

Also, why is there a trailing slash there?

Comment: `IIS` is serving different websites on both ports (8881 and 1500). The trailing slash works for getting a request to http://localhost/bacon and pass it to http://127.0.0.1:1500/ not to http://127.0.0.1:1500/bacon. You can find more on that here: https://serverfault.com/questions/379675/nginx-reverse-proxy-url-rewrite/725433#725433

Comment: Gotcha, okay. It then appears that you are getting a 502 for that specific JS file -- can you make a request to that directly? play with the path .e.g. `localhost/flutter_service_worker.js`, `localhost/bacon/flutter_service_worker.js` `localhost:1500/flutter_service_worker.js` and `localhost:1500/bacon/ flutter_service_worker.js` and prove that file exists and is being served? and from which path?

Comment: http://localhost:1500/flutter_service_worker.js is the only one that works. I'm guessing you are going to suggest to route that file individually on `Nginx`? I've tried that approach before and ended up with a circular reference with otter files down the road.

Comment: Review the error and access logs from nginx as they should show on what is going wrong when it proxies the request to IIS.

Answer (score 1):

Url rewrite of `proxy_pass` directive works only with http request and http redirect in response. That means, that if `http://127.0.0.1:1500/;` will reply with HTTP 30x Location: http://127.0.0.1:1500/aaaa/, nginx will rewrite it to http://localhost/bacon/aaaa/.

But this rewrite dose not touch response body. Any links in response HTML will be same - `<a href="/aaaa/"`, so no `/bacon/` part here.

To fix it there is two ways. First - edit your application. Replace all links with `/beacon/` prefix or use relative URL and add `<base href="/bacon/">` in head on each file.

If edit of file is not possible, you can rewrite body with ngx_http_sub_module. There is doc of module http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_sub_module.html

In this way you need to add `sub_filter` for all html constructions where is link used. For example

```
sub_filter_once off;
sub_filter ' href="/' ' href="/bacon/';
sub_filter ' src="/' ' src="/bacon/';
```

just need to be careful. You should put all `sub_filter` to `/bacon/` location.

Setup backend application is much preferred but sometimes only sub_filter can help.

Also there is third method but it can be used in some rare cases. If `/flutter_servivce_worker.js` doesn't exists in 127.0.0.1:8881 backend, you can add custom location for this file and proxy_pass to bacon backend:

```
location = /flutter_servivce_worker.js {
  proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:1500;
}
```

Sure this method can help in very limited cases when you are missing only few files and do not use any links.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your first app is loading **main.dart.js** from the second (at root path) because you forgot to change `<base href="/">` to `<base href="/bacon/">` in **index.html** file.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing to do with NGINX.

For the new site, the request is routed fine and HTML is loaded onto the browser. But the dependant static file references of the application are still pointed to the base location path '/'.

> Based on the chosen frontend language, the base route should be changed to /bacon

(or)

> create a folder with the name bacon and place the built files in that folder and serve the static content simply using Nginx with webserver configuration

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried?

```
# new website         
    location /new/ {
        proxy_pass          http://127.0.0.1:1500;
        proxy_http_version  1.1;
        gzip_static         on;
    }

    # old website
    location /old/ {
        proxy_pass          http://127.0.0.1:8881;
        proxy_http_version  1.1;
        gzip_static         on;
    }
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't change the route of my old website.